# Cancel current touch events until next touchstart

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch-event

I have to simulate longpress using javascript.

```
var timer;

$(element).on('touchend',function(e){

 clearTimeout(timer);


});

 $(element).on('touchstart',function(e){

  timer=setTimeout(function()
    {
        //some action
    },1000);

    return true;

});
```

When the action is triggered which is displaying a context menu, after that if finger is lifted then at touchend event the context menu hides . I want to avoid this.I want cancel all touch events until next touchstart
What should i do.
The problem is only in ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, did you try clear queue ??
maybe use `.stop()` to clear or `.clearQueue()`

ref: https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

ref: https://api.jquery.com/queue/

ref: https://api.jquery.com/stop/